# How to order the line by the number of elements in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a table. Each line has a different number of elements.

Here is the data:

```
set1 A B C D E
set2 2 4 7
set3 t 7 3 d 8 h f d
set4 j 3
```

How can I use R to rearrange the table by the number of elements in descending order?

```
set3 t 7 3 d 8 h f d
set1 A B C D E
set2 2 4 7
set4 j 3
```

Comment: Have you already read this data into R? What kind of data structure are you using to store it? You should show some example code that shows how to set the data up the same way you have it.

Comment: @Marius, Yes, I have tried to read the file by read.csv & read.table. However, I do see every line has the same length that is the longest line. For those shorter lines, some of the elements are empty.

Comment: Keep those vectors in a list structure. Then it's as simple as `x[order(-lengths(x))]`

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
df1[order(-apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) sum(x != '' & !is.na(x)))),]
```